# Click on burger menu

Tags: android

I've got a little problem in my action bar. I can only see my drawer by switching from left to right whereas I'd like to see it when I'm clicking on burger menu icon. Here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFC100"
                android:text="bite"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />



        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <include layout="@layout/drawer"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the java :

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        this.toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        this.drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,this.drawerLayout,0,0);
        this.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(this.drawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // synchroniser le drawerToggle après la restauration via onRestoreInstanceState
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

I'd like to keep this structure of code if it is possible.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar code which is working fine, try this

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 0,0) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open


                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works ! I've got one last question ! I'd like that my background scroll in the same time : I'd like to see the left part of my background when I'm on my drawer. Do you know how to do that ? Thank you again !

Comment: And regarding your other query, can you please give some details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the other constructor for ActionBarDrawerToggle, the one with the **toolbar parameter**.

`this.drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,this.drawerLayout,toolbar,0,0);`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works ! I've got one last question ! I'd like that my background scroll in the same time : I'd like to see the left part of my background when I'm on my drawer. Do you know how to do that ? Thank you again !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Currently when I'm scrolling in order to see my drawer, the drawer is in front of my previous page, I'd like that my previous page scroll in the same time. In fact at the end, i'd like to see my drawer and the left part of my previous page. I'm sorry my english is not good

Comment: So you want the main (background) page, to scroll to the top, when you open the Drawer on the left?

Comment: I  want the main page to scroll to the right in the same time. In fact, I want that my drawer "pushes" the main page to the right

Comment: Ah, that's a bit trickier. You're gonna need to define the drawer as a page inside a ViewPager, and have its pages width custom sized. I'm afraid I can't cover all of this right now. I'll try to find an example.